# Python not catching MemoryError

Tags: python, exception, out-of-memory

I've wrapped some code that can run out of memory with a try/except block. However, though a MemoryError is generated, it is not caught.

I have the following code:

```
    while True:
        try:
            self.create_indexed_vocab( vocab )
            self.reset_weights()
            break;
        except MemoryError:
            # Stuff to reduce size of vocabulary
            self.vocab, self.index2word = None, None
            self.syn0, self.syn1 = None, None

            self.min_count += 1
            logger.info( ...format string here... )
```

I get the following Traceback:

```
File "./make_model_tagged_wmt11.py", line 39, in <module>
  model.build_vocab(sentences)
File "/root/CustomCompiledSoftware/gensim/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 236, in build_vocab
  self.reset_weights()
File "/root/CustomCompiledSoftware/gensim/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 347, in reset_weights
  self.syn0 += (random.rand(len(self.vocab), self.layer1_size) - 0.5) / self.layer1_size
File "mtrand.pyx", line 1044, in mtrand.RandomState.rand (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:6523)
File "mtrand.pyx", line 760, in mtrand.RandomState.random_sample (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:5713)
File "mtrand.pyx", line 137, in mtrand.cont0_array (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:1300)
MemoryError
```

I'm running Python 2.7.3 under Ubuntu 12.04

The `reset_weights` line `self.syn0` is exactly the line I am expecting to raise the exception (it allocates a big array). The puzzling thing is that I can't catch the memory error and do things that will make the array size smaller.

Are there special circumstances that result in the `MemoryError` being unable to be caught?

Comment: are you sure those are the lines that throw the exception? try to change the except line to except: and print something there just to make sure those are the right lines.

Comment: @DannyElly it seems as though the stacktrace shows a call to reset_weights() which is the last line before the except. I expect that reset_weights is being called.

Comment: @Eponymous is the argument `vocab` in your call to `create_indexed_vocab` supposed to be `self.vocab` ? And, to @DannyElly's point, perhaps there's a call to `reset_weights` hidden in a the call to create_indexed_vocab? That likely wouldn't matter here, since it's reporting a MemoryError...

Comment: @Eponymous I would still change the except line and print something there. Oftentimes, we are positive we debug the right block of code when in fact the problem is in a different one. that can very frustrating. When I encounter such BUGs I just add as much prints as I can to make sure that I'm working on the right problem.

Comment: @apgwoz `vocab` and `self.vocab` are different. `vocab` is a local variable that takes 3-4 hours to calculate. `create_indexed_vocab` uses it to initialize `self.vocab` and `self.index2word`. There isn't a call to `reset_weights` in the `create_indexed_vocab`, it only calls the logger and built-ins.

Comment: @DannyElly `except:` didn't catch anything. I'm giving up. One way I haven't tried of catching the uncatchable exception is to put the allocation code and the rest in a separate process. I can pass the adjustment parameters and vocab through interprocess communication and detect if the process exits successfully through printing something. Ugly.

Comment: @Eponymous are you sure the lines in the try block throws an exception. Did you have prints before and after the suspected line (`self.reset_weights()`) and see only the before print. this is the best that I can help. I know I'm suggesting trivial and stupid pointers but we are all humans and sometimes we are missing obvious things. good luck to u!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Note that because of the underlying memory management architecture (C’s malloc() function), the interpreter may not always be able to completely recover from this situation; it nevertheless raises an exception so that a stack traceback can be printed, in case a run-away program was the cause.**

(See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError))

Usually, you can catch MemoryErrors nevertheless. Without knowing what exactly happens when a MemoryError gets thrown, I'd guess that you might not be able to catch it when shit really hit the fan and there's no more memory there to handle it.

Also, since you may not be able to really recover from it (see above), it probably wouldn't make that much sense to catch it. **You should really avoid running out of memory** and limiting the amount of memory your program uses by e.g. only allowing a list to have a limited size.

Comment: That hint in the docs is why I wrote this question. I want to know if uncatchable exceptions actually happen (and if it might be happening in my specific case) or if my python-fu was too low and there was a language nuance I was missing.

Comment: RAM is a shared resource, thus, avoiding running out of memory is impossible. Even if the `resource` module were available on MS-Windows so there was a built-in way to check memory, another process could eat up some of the memory you want between the time you check available memory and the time you allocate it. So the memory allocation cycle for a program that wants to use as much RAM as possible needs to be `while(allocation fails): adjust requirements; allocate`. In Python, the only way I know to detect a failed allocation is a `MemoryError`.

Comment: I'm giving up, so I'll give you the accepted answer. (Yours being the only answer.)

Comment: "by e.g. only allowing a list to have a limited size"  But what size?  Using large blocks of memory can speed up computations.  How do we find the right balance in Python, considering memory differs from machine to machine and minute to minute?

Comment: @Eponymous I know you made your comment many years ago and probably have learned that running out of memory is possible. Systems will have physical limits on how much storage they have and how much storage is available to user/system processes. Otherwise you could write a program that first filled RAM, then persistent storage, and crashed leaving the system potentially permanently broken. Even in 2023 it's possible to exceed virtual memory and system configuration will lead to process termination, or OS crash.