# When to catch MemoryError in Python?

Tags: python, memory-management

I am trying to understand when does it make sense to catch `MemoryError` in Python, I got two scenarios:

Scenario 1: MemoryError is successfully caught.

```
import numpy as np

try:
    a = np.ones(100000000000)
except MemoryError:
    print 'got memory error, plan B'
    a = np.ones(10) # this gets created
```

Scenario 2: My program freezes

```
silly = []
c = 0
try:
    while True:
        silly.append((str(c))) # just increasing the list
        c += 1
        if c % 1000000 == 0:
            print 'counter : {}'.format(c)
except MemoryError:
    print 'oops' # never get here
    silly.append('silly')
```

My guess is in the first case, python "knows" how much memory would need to be allocated, and thus raises a `MemoryError` exception. While in the second case python does not "know" how big I intent `silly` to be. However, `list` is a [dynamic array](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented); therefore, python should know that extending this array by a certain amount would cause a `MemoryError`, why is the exception not raised then?

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899910/python-not-catching-memoryerror) question, and the relevant paragraph from the docs is:

> exception MemoryError
>
> Raised when an operation runs out of memory but the situation may still be rescued
>   (by deleting some objects). The associated value is a
>   string indicating what kind of (internal) operation ran out of memory.
>   Note that because of the underlying memory management architecture
>   (C’s malloc() function), the interpreter may not always be able to
>   completely recover from this situation; it nevertheless raises an
>   exception so that a stack traceback can be printed, in case a run-away
>   program was the cause.

Though this helped me, I am still not very clear as to what is going on, and I did not get an exception as the docs seem to indicate.

My questions: Is my guess right on scenario 1? Why is `MemoryException` not raised in scenario 2?

I am using Python 2.7.5+, and I am on ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

In Python list is a linked list so the memory Exception `MemoryError` will be raised only when the system can't allocate additional memory.

This scenario occurs only when your `RAM (main memory)` is utilized to its maximum level most of the OS handles this scenario by moving less priority data to `Hard Disk` hence you don't get `MemoryError` in new OS but its better to handle this because the `legacy OS` don't have the above mentioned mechanism so the programer needs to handle it.

Comment: Python list is certainly a dynamic array : https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented

Comment: The second part of your answer certainly makes sense, but how does python know when to raise a `MemoryError` and when to start moving data to hard dist?

Answer (score 1):

The `MemoryError` is raised by OS not by **Python**.

> **Legacy OS** raise **MemoryError** immediately when it finds that memory is full, Where as Most of **latest OS** try to move the content to **Hard Disk** as it find that **Main Memory** is full and no room for new request, if its still can't be accommodated in **Allocated space of Hard Disk** or the ***current request size*** exceeds limit of data storage space allocated for this particular process in **RAM(Main Memory)**  then it raise's **MemoryError**.

The `MemoryError` raised by `OS` can be captured by your python program using **`try exception`**.

The `MemoryError` is also raised by `OS` when you make a request for memory that exceeds limit of `Main Memory` to store data.

> Example: *If you are using 512MB RAM and your OS allocated 200MB in RAM for data and rest for code, In that 200MB for your process 50MB Data space is allocated by OS and you make a request to store 100MB which exceeds limit hence OS raises **MemoryError** in this scenario too.*