# How to proceed with Python loop after memory crash

Tags: python

I am doing multiple nested loops for machine learning testing on large dataset

in these loops I test different algorithms and data set sizes

the problem is that I get crashes in the middle of the process with this error or any other error

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 194. MiB for an array with shape
> (1662, 15269) and data type float64

I want a way that no matter the error the code continues

here is my code

```
  for Size in [10, 100, 1000, 10000,100000, 1000000]:
        

        df_reps_all = pd.read_sql("EXEC GetReps_Idea14 " + str(Size) , conn)
        df_results_all = pd.read_sql("EXEC GetResults14 " + str(Size)  , conn)

       for Model in ["SVC","LOG", "RF", "GNB", "KNN"]:
            
            multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
            multilabel_binarizer.fit(df['Code'])
            y = multilabel_binarizer.transform(df['Code'])
             
            
            if Model == "LOG":
                mdl = LogisticRegression()
            elif Model == "RF":
                mdl = RandomForestClassifier()
            elif Model == "GNB":
                mdl = GaussianNB()
            elif Model == "KNN":
                mdl = KNeighborsClassifier()
            elif Model == "SVC":
                mdl = SVC()
            print (120)
                
            
            
            clf = OneVsRestClassifier(mdl)
         
            y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, dfMethod, y, cv=3, n_jobs=-1)
```

***P.S. my question is not how to fix that error.
my question is how to proceed with code no matter what error I get***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the memory error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347397/how-to-solve-the-memory-error-in-python)

Comment: @enzo Thanks, but my question is not how to solve the error. my question is how to proceed with the code no matter what error I get

Comment: Wrap the offending code in `try ... except ... finally`? Beyond that, there isn't much to say. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue in case of such "crash" you need to catch and handle the `MemoryError` exception.

Find the smallest part of your code where the exception occurs (there should be a line number in the full stack trace) and wrap it in `try .. except` block.

```
try:
    ... some code that can run out of memory ...
except MemoryError:
    pass
```

You may want to do something else, like some cleanup instead of `pass` which will do nothing, and just continue to the next line of code, but there isn't enough information in your question for a better recommendation.

If you want to ignore all other errors, replace `MemoryError` with `Exception` which is the base call, and will catch all exceptions that can be caught.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [try/except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899910/python-not-catching-memoryerror). But it might not always work for memory exceptions ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899910/python-not-catching-memoryerror)).
A workaround might be to separate it to 2 scripts, a master script that submits the jobs, and a worker that runs it.

Something like this:

```
master.py
----------
for Size in [10, 100, 1000, 10000,100000, 1000000]:
    for Model in ["SVC","LOG", "RF", "GNB", "KNN"]:
        os.sysmem(f"python worker.py {Size} {Model}")


worker.py
---------
Size = int(sys.agv[1])
Model = sys.argv[2]

df_reps_all = pd.read_sql("EXEC GetReps_Idea14 " + str(Size) , conn)
df_results_all = pd.read_sql("EXEC GetResults14 " + str(Size)  , conn)

multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
multilabel_binarizer.fit(df['Code'])
y = multilabel_binarizer.transform(df['Code'])
    

if Model == "LOG":
    mdl = LogisticRegression()
elif Model == "RF":
    mdl = RandomForestClassifier()
elif Model == "GNB":
    mdl = GaussianNB()
elif Model == "KNN":
    mdl = KNeighborsClassifier()
elif Model == "SVC":
    mdl = SVC()
print (120)
    


clf = OneVsRestClassifier(mdl)

y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, dfMethod, y, cv=3, n_jobs=-1)
```

So even if the worker fails, you will still be able to continue with the next parameters set

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use try:... except:... to catch the error and ignore it, for example:

```py
try:
    # your code that may throw an error
except:
    pass
```

However, ignore an error and do nothing about it is usually not recommended.

Comment: beware! because this doesn't specify an Exception type, it'll catch unexpected exceptions inheriting from `BaseException` like `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy